# How to expand dropdown menu using css , javascript and html?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a drop down menu in my page , when user click the dropdown menu buttom the button should expand and display the data .

here is what I want [image]

Here is HTML

```
<div claa="demo">
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

in css I tried to set borders to none but that solution look very agry , can some help what I need to do to get what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Add one more class to Button for expand/collapse and target that class to control the ul element.

for example:

```
.expand + ul {display: block;}
.collapse + ul {display: none;}
```

Comment: can you show that in jsfiddle? I tried but stil have that agry one :(

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing it.

- You can set a by default height to it just to show -Punkt 1 like height: 60px and toggle between height: auto on the click function binded to caret class.

Or

- You can toggle between showing and hiding the drop-down menu class on the above mentioned click function.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( '.dropdown-toggle' ).on( 'click touchstart', function(){
  $( '.dropdown-menu' ).toggleClass( 'dropdown-menu-open' );
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.dropdown-menu-open {
  max-height: 200px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div claa="demo">
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Use jQuery to toggle a class on the ul. By setting .dropdown-menu to max-height: 0; overflow: hidden; we hide the content. We can then apply styles to the .dropdown-menu-open to increase the max-height to show the contents.

Comment: Thanks bro but that u can get just by normal bootstrap , here is your  solution http://jsfiddle.net/w98a1fjs/ check youself does that resembeles to what I want I think no, The whole button should expand not only text

Comment: That can be achieved by CSS. I've done it here - http://jsfiddle.net/w98a1fjs/4/

You don't actually want to physically have the dropdown items inside the button you just want the appearance they are. You can style the div that wraps both the button and the ul to achieve this.